# Hiding li element using sub-element's information

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey

I load a web page from the internet (say www.google.com or whatever). This page is written in HTML. Suppose in this code there is this fragment.

```
<ul class="CLASS">
     <li>
          <div class="DIV1"></div>
          <a href="SOMETHING1"></a>
     </li>                             //Hide this li
     <li>
          <div class="DIV2"></div>
          <a href="SOMETHING2"></a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <div class="DIV3"></div>
          <a href="SOMETHING3"></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I want to know if there is a way to hide the section (the li section) that I mention in the previous code ("Hide this li") **as soon as** I load the page. In my screen, I don't want to execute the section li that I mention.

I did some research and I think that the Firefox extension Greasemonkey does it. What will be the script to add to do this ? Or, there is a different way (without Greasemonkey).

Comment: Why do you keep mentioning Firefox? Are you writing code or playing with developer tools?

Comment: Hi,

What I want to do is : When I load a WEB PAGE (I thing that's the point I don't mention precisely), I want a script (or something else) that's hide what I was talking above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using only html and css. I would do it using javascript and a library (I use jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a[href=SOMETHING1]').parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for answering me.

Well, how can I use javascript and jQuery in Firefox for example. I Wrote the script in a Firefox extensions ?

Comment: You can use jquery in any browser you want. just add this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> before your closing </body> tag and immediately after that script add <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a[href=SOMETHING1]').parent().hide();
});</script>

Comment: Probably a good idea to wrap the `SOMETHING1` in double inverted commas, i.e. `$('li a[href="SOMETHING1"]').parent().hide()`;

Comment: Sorry. I don't mention that I don't write the code but I try to do it from a web page (that I requested from Internet).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my problem using Greasemonkey and your code.
Terry is definitely right. You need to wrap the SOMETHING1 in double inverted commas, whithout it doesn't work.
It work perfectly.